# Awesomium + AJAX load local files

Tags: c++, ajax, awesomium

I am using Awesomium with C++ and I'd like to load local pages with AJAX.
Awesomium is running on the chrome engine as far as I know, and chrome has disabled loading local files through ajax calls.

However this can be enabled setting this flag in awesomium config:

```
WebConfig wc = WebConfig();
wc.additional_options.Push(Awesomium::ToWebString("--allow-file-access-from-files"));
web_core_ = WebCore::Initialize(wc);
```

I think this is correct?
Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

Anyway, my AJAX doesn't succeed, it fails and the page does not load.

the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: u,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: "html"
}).success(function() {
    test("yes");
}).error(function() {
    test("no");
});
```

// prints "no" when the function is called.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction?
I think it should be possible, I've seen others on this site claiming to be using awesomium and ajax calls.

Best regards.

Comment: Change your error callback to `.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(errorThrown); });`. You will get more information on what went wrong.

Comment: @isim I did this, and it only printed out one thing: "error". >_>

Comment: Did you try `console.log(errorThrown)` and/or `console.log(textStatus)`? Hopefully, one of them will give you something more useful.

Comment: @isim I did, but they printed nothing.  this awesomium "browser" runs in a c++ app, there's no console.log() like in the actual chrome browser, but I did print them out with regular javascript. still no information from them.